# Paginación en Frontend y Backend

Tags: angular

Un saludo para todos los amigos del foro, mi duda se encamina a saber como paginar desde el backend, digamos que en el frontend Angular, deseo paginar una tabla, digamos mostrar 10 registros por página al usuario.

El paginador muestre las páginas totales o sea, 1, 2, 3...10, pero en la base de datos tengo un millón de registros, esta cantidad no es buena práctica cargarla en una consulta, por lo que debo realizar la carga en bloques digamos de 200 registros.

Al enviar estos 200 registros al frontend, el componente ngTable procederá a calcular la paginación.

La pregunta es: ¿Como enlazar las paginaciones de bloques sucesivos con las de bloques previos? Ej: el bloque1 va desde la página 1 hasta la 20, el bloque2 carga desde la página 21 - 40, ¿Cómo decirle a Angular que después de la página 20 del primer bloque cargue la página 21 del segundo bloque que se carga de la base de datos?

Comment: Hola para poder ayudarte tienes que compartir tú código, mostrarnos donde te lanza error que has intentado. Te invito ha hacer un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y sobre cualquier duda puedes visitar esta [sección de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). también seria bueno en que lenguaje estas programando tu backend y tu motor de bbdd para ayudarte en la consulta suerte

Comment: Mira el ejemplo en http://ng-table.com/#/loading/demo-external-array . Básicamente tienes que enviarle al backend cuántas filas quieres (200) y qué página. El backend debe aplicar un offset que es `200*página` y devolver un objeto que contenga en una llave los 200 registros y en otra el total (1 millón). El paginador de la tabla sabrá cómo enumerar las paginaciones tal que ofrezca 1M/200 páginas

Comment: El lenguaje es Java 8, el backend puede ser Spring 5 o simplemente Java EE 8; la base de datos Postgresql 9.5, aun estamos valorando la arquitectura a desarrollar, y el cliente cuenta con una base de más de 5 millones de registros, es por eso que pregunto cómo paginarla desde Angular, que se usará como frontend. Llevo algunos días  googleando y la verdad no he encontrado en concreto como hacerle. Para la respuesta a mi pregunta no espero un fragmento de código o un ejemplo hecho (aunque si lo hubiera sería grandioso), sino más bien un "Know-How".

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que ya encontraste la respuesta, pero para próximos compañeros en busqueda de la respuesta aquí está.

En mi caso, he hecho paginación desde la base de datos de esta forma:

### Ejemplo

```
INSERT INTO @example SELECT ... FROM @table WHERE something BETWEEN (@index * @pageSize) + 1 AND (@index + 1) * @pageSize; RETURN
```

Donde estas dos variables enviadas desde el cliente en Angular (las puedes recuperar del table), al backend y de ahí a la función en la BD.
@index INT,
@pageSize INT

**Index** será la posición actual de la paginación y **pageSize** pues la cantidad de items que aparecerán por página.

Saludos y pura vida.

Answer (score 0):

**Actualización:**
Un ejemplo sería algo así.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () "indice", 
        ...**elements**...
    FROM **table**              
    WHERE "indice" BETWEEN (page_Index * page_Size) + 1 AND (page_Index + 1) * page_Size
);
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Por favor cuando vayas a dar una respuesta debes dar la explicación de lo que haces, para que el usuario que realizó la pregunta puede entender claramente que es lo que está haciendo en su código. ¡Feliz día!

Comment: Hola, gracias por la observación, es mi primer contribución y no pensé que el ejemplo fuese muy confuso, lo tomaré muy en cuenta para la próxima, aclarar mejor. Saludos.